# Лучшая практика при создании селектора для первого и последнего child'а в контейнере

Tags: html, css

Представим,что есть следующая разметка:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

Есть родительский контейнер и 2 чайлда с одинаковым названием в классах. Мне нужно кажому задать определенные свойства, они отличаются. Мне пришло в голову воспользоваться псевдо-селектором `first-child,last-child`, но стало интересно, есть ли еще какие-то варианты реализации данной задачи с помощью css?

Comment: в данном случае можно еще так https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/r8wa7325/

Comment: Вполне себе стандартное решение использовать данные псевдо-селекторы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант решения псевдокласс: [**nth-child**](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)

---

### Описание

Псевдокласс **`:nth-child`** используется для добавления стиля к элементам на основе нумерации в дереве элементов.

Синтаксис
элемент:**`nth-child(odd | even | <число> | <выражение>) {...}`**

---

### Значения

- **`odd`** - Все нечетные номера элементов.
- **`even`** - Все четные номера элементов.
- **`число`** - Порядковый номер дочернего элемента относительно своего родителя. Нумерация начинается с 1, это будет первый элемент в списке.
- **`выражение`** - Задается в виде an+b, где a и b целые числа, а n
  счетчик, который автоматически принимает значение 0, 1, 2...

Если a равно нулю, то оно не пишется и запись сокращается до b. Если b равно нулю, то оно также не указывается и выражение записывается в форме an. a и b могут быть отрицательными числами, в этом случае знак плюс меняется на минус, например: 5n-1.

За счет использования отрицательных значений a и b некоторые результаты могут также получиться отрицательными или равными нулю. Однако на элементы оказывают влияние только положительные значения из-за того, что нумерация элементов начинается с 1.

В табл. 1 приведены некоторые возможные выражения и ключевые слова, а также указано, какие номера элементов будут задействованы.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/189325)

Comment: @AivanF. да, вроде, это не ответ-ссылка. Вся суть в ответе, а ссылка лишь дополняет ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Пример использования псевдо-классов :first-child и :last-child, авось кому пригодится из новичков:

```css
ul{
 list-style-type:none;
}
ul li{
 width:100px;
 height:10px;
 background:#ccc;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
ul li:first-child{
 background:#4cd964;
}
ul li:last-child{
 background:#802420;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>:first-child и :last-child</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li>&nbsp;</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```